# Proving using Beta Reductions (Lambda Calculus)

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am working on proving something by using Lambda Calculus and Beta Reductions, and I was following along a tutorial on another problem and attempted to carry over the knowledge onto a different problem and I am a little confused on the last step.

The problem is to prove $\textbf{or true false}$.

Here are my steps: (if there are any improvements or errors please let me know)

Step 1: Begin writing the identity for **OR** along with the parameters **true** and **false**.

$(\lambda x. \lambda y.(x ~ true ~ y)) ~ true false$

Step 2: Replace the $x$ terms with true.

$(\lambda y.(true ~ true ~ y)) ~ false $

Step 3: Replace the $y$ terms with false.

$ true ~ true ~ false \equiv (true ~ true) false $

Step 4: (I am a little shaky on this step, however I saw it done this way). Expand on one of the terms by replacing with it's identity. So we break true into:

$ (\lambda x. \lambda y. x) true ~ false $

Step 5: Again, replace x with true.

$(\lambda y.true) ~ false$

Step 6: $\textbf{this is the step i am most confused on}$
It looks as if since there is no way we can distribute the false to the y we simply just drop both of them since it is not an applicable function. Which then returns you with **true**, which stands to reason that true or false is true.

Can anyone shed light on Step 6? Or if I am correct and thats the rationale please let me know!

Comment: I'm just going to change my answer so it answers the actual problem, which is step 6.

Comment: You should think of $\lambda y.\ z$ as a function which takes an input, discards it, and  always return $z$. This is the constantly-$z$ function, in a sense. A function argument $y$ does not have to be used in its body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let:
$$ true = \lambda x ~ y . x $$
$$ false = \lambda x ~ y . y$$
$$ or = \lambda x ~ y .((x ~ true) y) $$

So this is what you wrote:

$$or ~ true ~ false \rhd_{\beta} true$$

$$  \Bigg ( \Big( \lambda x ~ y . (x ~ true) y \Big) true \Bigg) ~ false $$
$$ \Bigg ( \lambda y. \Big ((true ~ true) y \Big) \Bigg) false $$
$$ ((true ~ true) ~ false) $$

Unwrap $true$.

$$ \Big( (\lambda x ~ y . x) ~ true) \Big) ~ false $$
$$ \color{red}{(\lambda y . true) ~ false } \rhd true $$

In the red step, which is what's burdening you, you're just consuming the $false$, why? Because there are no free $y$ variables in $true \equiv (\lambda x~ y. x)$. This is rule-(e) for substitution.

> **Definition 1.12 (Substitution)** For any $M, N, x$, define $[N/x]M$ to be the result of substituting $N$ for every free occurrence of $x$ in $M$, and changing bound variables to avoid clashes. The precise definition is by induction on $M$, as follows ***(after [CF58, p.94])***.
>
> (a) $[N/x]x \equiv N$
>
> (b) $[N/x]a \equiv a$ for all atoms $a \not \equiv x$
>
> (c) $[N/x](PQ) \equiv ([N/x]P)([N/x]Q)$
>
> (d) $[N/x](\lambda x.P) \equiv (\lambda x.P)$
>
> **(e) $[N/x](\lambda y.P) \equiv P$ if $x \not \in FV(P)$.**
>
> (f) $[N/x](\lambda y.P) \equiv \lambda y. [N/x]P$ if $x \in FV(P)$ and $y \not \in FV(N)$.
>
> (g) $[N/x](\lambda y.P) \equiv \lambda z. [N/x][z/y]P$ if $x \in FV(P)$ and $y \in FV(N)$.

Note: $FV(P)$ stands for the set of **free variables** of $P$.

Comment: Sorry! Corrected to what you asked.

Comment: perfect, thanks for your help, just wanted to make sure my rationale was correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree with this answer: the important part is that there are no free $y$ variables in $\mathrm{true}$, not in $\lambda y.\mathrm{true}$ (which cannot have free $y$ variables anyways). It's also probably useful to note that rule (e) is redundant with respect to the other rules (which is a very good exercise to understand substitution in the $\lambda$-calculus).